# why is *pp[0] equal to **pp

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

So I am trying to figure out pointers and I read some posts on pointers to pointers but I can't still figure out why this program runs without trouble

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(){
    char* p = "abc";

    char** pp[2];
    pp[0] = &p;
    assert(*pp[0]==**pp);

    printf("Comparison: %s, %s\n",**pp, *pp[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand now the memory would look something like this

```
Memory Address (hex)    Variable name    Contents
1000                                     'a' == 97 (ASCII)
1001                                     'b' == 98
1002                                     'c' == 99
1003                                     0
...
2000-2003               p                1000 hex
...
3000-3003               pp[0]            2000 hex
```

At this point assuming that I got the memory thing right...
I would expect *pp[0] to go into memory and say...

So pp[0] points to the address of p, which is 0x2000, and by dereferencing I would expect to get the contents of address 0x2000 which in my point of view means that I would get the 0x1000 but that is not the case since the output of the program is:

OUTPUT

```
abc, abc
```

In the case of **pp I think it first dereferences pp which will give us the contents of whatever pp is pointing to, that means the contents of 0x2000 (which is 0x1000) and then by dereferencing again we get the contents of address 0x1000

Why would they be equal? Where am I missing something

Comment: Because `pp` can be short for `&pp[0]` and `**&pp[0]` is obviously the same as `*pp[0]` (because `*&x` is the same as `x`, whenever it works).

Answer (score 5):

In most contexts, if you have an array `a`, then `a` is short for `&a[0]`. (There are some exceptions, such as with `sizeof a` or `&a`).

So `**pp` really means `**&pp[0]`.

`&pp[0]` is the address of `pp[0]`, so `*&pp[0]` is equivalent to just `pp[0]`, so `**&pp[0]` is equivalent to `*pp[0]`.

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense and this is probably how I will look at it in the future but my reasoning was following more according to @Peter which mentions that *pp[0] dereferences effectively twice otherwise it won't make sense to me according to what I wrote, I hope that both answers are not in conflict and thanks for the help

Comment: @OmarMuñoz If `pp` is an array, `pp[0]` actually dereference anything under the hood. (Well, it doesn't dereference any more than accessing any other variable would)

Answer (score 2):

pp[0] is always the same as *pp, no matter what type of pointer you're dealing with.

Given the high operator precedence of the square brackets, *pp[0] is the same as *(pp[0]) ... which would, by the sentence above, be the same as *(*pp), which is the same as **pp.  Q.E.D..

Answer (score 2):

> So pp[0] points to the address of p, which is 0x2000, and by dereferencing I would expect to get the contents of address 0x2000

That's were your reasoning strays, but understandably so. In C, the right hand side of an assignment, or generally an evaluation of an lvalue (vulgo: variable), more precisely an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, *is already a dereferencing!* For example, `int i, j=0; i=j;` effectively dereferences `j`; `j`  is an address constant, and the assignment concerns the value stored there, `j`'s value, so that the assignment amounts to `i=0`. Other languages, like Algol68, were more precise: one would effectively write `int i; int *pi = i;`, which makes complete sense (pi now points to i).

That's why when you dereference `pp[0]`  *explicitly*, with `*pp[0]`, you are dereferencing it effectively twice: First you look *at the contents of the address 0x2000*, which is 0x1000, and then you dereference that in order to read the memory at 0x1000.